# How to show more x-axes in core-plot chart

Tags: objective-c, core-plot, ios-charts

According to our needs, we need to show the x-axis information at the top and bottom of the chart, how to show more x-axes? THX

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several of the Core Plot example apps show how to add multiple axes in a graph. See, for example, the "Axis Demo" in the *Plot Gallery* app. Position one x-axis at the top and the other at the bottom using the `axisConstraints` or `orthogonalCoordinateDecimal`.